# Increase in momentum of a particle falling into a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

From the point of view of an external observer at a fixed distance above a black hole, the linear momentum a free falling particle increases exponentially with Schwarzchild time. (This happens when the particle is very close to the horizon.) I am having trouble making this compatible with the fact that the above mentioned observer does not feel an increase of the gravitational force due to the black hole and the particle. Is this due to some sort of red-shift?

Answer (score 0):

The event horizon is a surface from which light cannot move outwards from, all light here is either 'stuck'  from the point of view of an observer at infinity, or moving inwards. Light emmited just outside this region can move outward very slowly, and moves outward faster the further it is away from the horizon.

So yes it is related to redshift, the amount of time it takes for light to escape from an object falling in to the blank hole to infinity increases to infinity as the object approaches the event horizon